# JHipster Spring Boot modularization split package

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jhipster, java-9, module-info

I am trying to modularize a JHipster 5 (Spring Boot 2) application and I ran into a split package problem.

In module-info.java I have the following conflicting automatic modules:

```
requires problem.spring.web;
requires problem;
requires jackson.datatype.problem;
```

When I build the project with Maven, I get several errors due to conflicting package name `org.zalando.problem` like this:

```
error: the unnamed module reads package org.zalando.problem from both problem and jackson.datatype.problem
error: module problem.spring.web reads package org.zalando.problem from both jackson.datatype.problem and problem
```

I would like to know how can I solve this issue. Would I have to wait for the third party library to be modularized too? What would be a nice way to solve this conflict?

[This article](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Split-Packages) explains a bit on how to solve Split Packages problems. I applied it to solve the split package between `jsr305` and `java.xml.ws.annotation` by using `--patch-module` argument when building, as explained [here](https://blog.codefx.org/java/jsr-305-java-9/). However the project did not compile when I tried the same for these packages.

The source for this project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/selzlein/jhipster5java10)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JARs that split a package as modules, `--patch-module` is the only way, but it's an arduous one. Beyond patching, you also need to craft the rest of the module graph. Say you're patching module *megacorp* with the content of *start.up*, then:

- you have to make *megacorp* read all of *start.up*'s dependencies with `--add-reads`
- you have to make all modules that use *start.up* read *megacorp* with `--add-reads`
- you have to ensure that *start.up* is not on the module path

This can be quite complicated, particularly if you're fighting Maven along the way. Are you sure, there is no way to simply merge the two artifacts?

If not, I'd say this project might not be ready for modularization.